# How can i get data set of illness and not illness people?

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny, covid-19, nucleotide-models, sars-cov-2

I'm reading a virology paper where the authors made a classification for the patients as to whether they had a specific disease outcome or not against the underlying sequence ...

> The research focused on two different class of DNA which are Hepatitis B Virus
> (HBV) Genotype B nucleotide sequence and Non-HBV nucleotide sequences`

- How can I get the data set or how can search to find it ?
- How can data sets of sequences date classify between illness and asymptomatic patients?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a link to the paper you're referring to. If the paper does not point to the dataset it analyzes, the best way to access the data (if it's not restricted access) is to email the corresponding author. Also, what do you mean by "sequences of illness and not illness people"?

Comment: Also, many researchers deposit their data at NCBI GEO: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/
...loads of stuff there.

Answer (score 2):

The data set will be available on [Genbank](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/), you simply search for the "authors surname and HBV" and their entire data set should be revealed.

The HBV genome is 5Kb, the smallest viral genome so its not alot of data.

I am confused by "Genotype B nucleotide sequence and non-HBV nucleotide sequences". What I suspect is the investigators looked at HBV genotype B in comparison to HBV genotypes A, C to I. Essentially they wanted to assess the relationship between genetic variation and pathogenesis, which is an attempt to assess virus-induced cancer. Obviously I don't know the paper but I'm aware of the basic research front in this area. HBV has a very wierd evolution and I personally wouldn't want to investigate it.